# Applying background-color to specific box

Tags: html, css

I want to color the 1st, 6th, 7th, 12th, 13th, and 18th boxes. Is there a quick method to do it in CSS

```css
.a {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: teal;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nos. are of the form **6n** and **6n+1**.
So, add a selector `.a:nth-of-type(6n), .a:nth-of-type(6n + 1)`.
Add `background-color: red;` to them.

More about `:nth-of-type()` from **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type)**:

> The `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class represents an element that has an+b siblings with the same expanded element name before it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and has a parent element.

**Snippet :**

```css
.a{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:teal;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
.a:nth-of-type(6n), .a:nth-of-type(6n + 1){
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div><br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```